# Proper way to migrate advanced code in JS for old browsers

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have some code in javascript in EC6, but I need it to open on old browsers (perfectly on Samsung S4). I'm testing with Safari 5. 
For compiling code I've chosen webpack + babel, but whatever configuration I choose there is one error: 'SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '.' instead' and it's only shown on old browsers. 
For example, removing all code, except this:

```
    import io from 'socket.io-client';
    let socket = io();
```

Gives following error in Safari 5:
"SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found '.' instead"

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "knife",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "phaser": "^3.20.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^10.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './game/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {
              targets: 'dead'
            }]]
          },
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the proper way for compiling js files with webpack and babel for this purpose?

Comment: Babel requires you to specify the compatibility level. It sounds like you didn't configure it properly.

Comment: If you want more specific help, you need to post the line that's getting the error and the original code that generated it.

Comment: I edited original question and added some specific information, including webpack.config.js and package.json

Comment: `import` was added in Safari 10.1, it can't be used in Safari 5.

Comment: Isn't there a way to compile, so it will work on Safari 5 too?